# Trying to use prepared statements would this work or do I have the complete wrong idea?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

So first off, im generating the menus for that page from database.

First of all, do I really need to prepare all queries? it seems alot more complicated than the simple Query > fetch > done.

Id probably guess that the way i've done it is wrong. But i find it easier to try then find out what i done wrong as i feel it's easier to learn that way.

So what parts are pointless or incorrect?

```
function menu() {
global $db;
$pagename = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
// alternate ussage notes bind_param('sdi', $string, $decimal, $integer);
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `p_id` FROM `pages` WHERE `name` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $pagename);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($page_id);
if ($stmt->num_rows()) { $isindb = true; }
else { $isindb = false; }
$stmt->fetch();
//echo $page_id; //uncomment to debug
$stmt->close(); // not sure if its closed too early. 
if ($isindb) {
// great. generate the menu.
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `menu_items` WHERE `d_id` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $page_id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store();
$stmt->bind_result($menulink_id, $menulink_d_id, $menulink_icon, $menulink_href, $menulink_title, $menulink_new_tab);
echo '<li><a href="index.php" id="top-link" class="skel-panels-ignoreHref"><span class="fa fa-home">Dasne Home</span></a></li>';
while ($r=$stmt->fetch()) {
if ($menulink_new_tab) { echo '<li><a href="'.$menulink_href.'" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-'.$menulink_icon.'">'.$menulink_title.'</span></a></li>'; }
else { echo '<li><a href="'.$menulink_href.'"><span class="fa fa-'.$menulink_icon.'">'.$menulink_title.'</span></a></li>'; }
}
$stmt->close();
// close if isindb
}
else {
// give default menu 
default_menu();
}
// close function
}
```

Also can you still use data from a prepared query after closing the statement?

Comment: You don't have to use PDO if you don't want to. Use `mysqli_*`, just make sure you escape all your input correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> do I really need to prepare all queries?

Yes.

> it seems alot more complicated

Yes. Because mysqli is not intended to be used as is, being only a low-level API, while you have to use a higher level abstraction library.

> So what parts are pointless or incorrect?

This is a clearly offtopic question.

> i find it easier to try then find out what i done wrong

Indeed, but you are doing it wrong way. Instead of "trying" A LOT of code you have to try with one alone query.

So, get rid of most of the code, leave only one query to run, and write it using [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info).

Comment: But my question are will that work? For example I use store then bind results and fetch, what is storing doing? Can I just bind and fetch results, also when I'm binding results as variables will that take the information in that column order or am I calling to the information in an completely incorrect way?